# stopping time for simple symmetric random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $\{S_n\}$ denote a simple symmetric random walk starting at $0$, and let $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ denote the natural filtration from the sequence of i.i.d. steps of this random walk.

Define the last exit time as
$$T= \max\{n\geq 0 : S_n = 10\}.$$
Because $S_n$ is a simple symmetric random walk, then $\mathbb{P}(T = k) = 0$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, because the state $10$ is null recurrent. If we take $\mathcal{F}_k$ to be complete (it contains the probably zero sets) then $\{T = k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k$.

Does this mean that $T$ is actually a stopping time?

Comment: Why would the state $10$ being null recurrent imply $\mathbb{P}(T=k)=0$ for all $k$?

Comment: I don't really think that the event $\{ T = k \} \in \mathcal{F}_k,$ can you expand on that?

Comment: @user6247850 because the random walk will visit 10 infinitely many times almost surely.

Comment: @AlanChung The event $\{T=k\}$ has probability zero, and I was thinking we could let $\mathcal{F}_k$ be complete, so it could contain all the probability zero sets.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't see that it's a max instead of a min.  Then yes, it is a stopping time for the completed filtration.

Comment: yes, its a (trivially unbounded) stopping time